# How do I make this code countdown second to second?

Tags: swift, swift2

I have this code for a countdown but it doesn't refresh every second. It just pauses as soon as it loads. How do I make it refresh every second so it shows a second to second countdown?

```
var dateComponents = NSDateComponents()

    dateComponents.day = 25
    dateComponents.month = 12
    dateComponents.year = 2015
    dateComponents.second = 0

       let christmasDay = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)!

     let durationDateComponents = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.components( [.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate(), toDate: christmasDay, options: [])

    minUntilHoliday.text =  "\(durationDateComponents.minute) months and"

    secUntilHoliday.text = "\(durationDateComponents.second) days."
```

Comment: Are you using a timer or a dispatch_source? It helps if you add the code you are using for that. How many times are you going to ask this question?

Comment: Pardon? This is my first time asking this question. And I don't know what I'm using, this is the following code that is working, nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could drop that into a function:

```
func callEverySecond() {
     var dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
     dateComponents.day = 25
     dateComponents.month = 12
     dateComponents.year = 2015
     dateComponents.second = 0

     let christmasDay = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)!

     let durationDateComponents = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.components( [.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate(), toDate: christmasDay, options: [])

     minUntilHoliday.text =  "\(durationDateComponents.minute) months and"

     secUntilHoliday.text = "\(durationDateComponents.second) days."
}
```

Then, call the function with an NSTimer (in your viewDidLoad):

```
let timeTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "callEverySecond", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: thats the right way. As a side comment: Store the timer property in the your Controller Instance if existing and when you leaving this controller than call `if timer.valid { timer.invalidate() }` this will stop the counter and will not be a problem on dealloc / deist